# catkin: dependency on package that generates headers

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, catkin, dependencies, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

- I have a package A that generates some c++ header files and some python code.
- I have a package B that depends on the header files from A.

I have problems creating good CMakeLists.txt that ensures that the headers in A always are built before building B.

I realize this is very much like the message generation concept, where packages can rely on messages from another package being built ahead of time.

Can I create the CMakeLists.txt for package A in such a way that a certain custom command always is ensured to run before targets from package B are being built?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/342048/catkin:-dependency-on-package-that-generates-headers/) by [knxa](https://answers.ros.org/users/29756/knxa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 811 on 2020-01-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-01-20**:
This seems like a general CMake question, not necessarily Catkin related (inter-target dependency declaration is a bit of CMake functionality).

Is

> I realize this is very much like the message generation concept

the reason you post it here?

**Comment by [knxa](https://answers.ros.org/users/29756/knxa/) on 2020-01-20**:
I had the impression that inter-package dependency was where catkin shines. And I found it likely that the solution would use a concept similar to the message generation concept. Also I wondered if the solution could relate to catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS. I apologize if this is a misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem only arises with `catkin_make` which builds all packages in a single CMake context.

The package A needs to add the target(s) which generate the files to the following variable which will be exported through the CMake config file of the package:

`list(APPEND ${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS <your-target-name(s)-here>)`

And package B needs to add a proper target dependency onto the value of the exported variable for all target which need the generated files:

`add_dependency(<your-library-or-executable-target> ${a_exported_targets})`

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2020-01-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0